# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x^{10}}{1+x^{14}} \right)^{2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

This is a integration question from a previous calculus exam:

> Evaluate $$\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x^{10}}{1+x^{14}} \right)^{2} \, dx$$

I rewrote it as $$\lim \limits_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b \left(\frac{x^{10}}{1+x^{14}} \right)^{2} \, dx,$$ where do I go on from there?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{14}\int \frac{x^7 14x^{13}}{(1 + x^{14})^2}dx& \underbrace{=}_{\color{red}{\text{by parts}}}\frac{1}{14}\bigg( -x^7\frac{1}{1 + x^{14}} + 7\color{#05f}{\int \frac{x^6}{1+x^{14}}dx}\bigg) \\&= \frac{1}{14}\bigg(\arctan(x^7) -\frac{x^7}{1 + x^{14}}\bigg) + C\end{align}$$

For $$\color{#05f}{\int \frac{x^6}{1+x^{14}}dx = \frac{1}{7}\arctan (x^7) + C}$$ let $v = x^7$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{a^n+x^n}~dx~=~a^{k-n}~\frac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\frac\pi n\bigg).~$ Now all that's left to do is

differentiating both sides with regard to *a*, and giving appropriate values to the three

parameters. The initial identity can be proven by letting $x=at$ and $u=\dfrac1{1+t^n}~,~$

followed by recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and

applying Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: @RonGordon: What exactly seems to be the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you addressed that.  My apologies.